# Не могу сохранить текущего пользователя через everyauth

Tags: node.js, javascript

Почитал справку, пошерстил гугл в поисках подобной проблемы, и я оказался не одинок, на гитхабе проекта everyauth люди тоже сталкивались с данной проблемой, но то что им помогло, мне не помогло.

Суть такова, проходит авторизация, и мне надо сохранить найденного (или созданного) пользователя из БД в сессионную переменную, что бы потом хелпером ее оттуда вытягивать для вьюхи. Просто информация о пользователе из соц сети сохранятся, в том числе и в хелпере самого everyauth.
Вот код app.js

```
var express     = require('express')
  , everyauth   = require('everyauth')
  , Promise     = everyauth.Promise
  , util        = require('util')
  , mongoose    = require('mongoose')
  , routes      = require('./routes')
  , _           = require('underscore')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/base');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

// Everyauth settings above that app.configure

everyauth.twitter
  .consumerKey('secretKey')
  .consumerSecret('secret')
  .findOrCreateUser(function (session, accessToken, accessTokenSecret, twitterUserData){
      var promise = this.Promise();
      User.findOrCreateByUidAndNetwork(twitterUserData.id, 'twitter', twitterUserData, promise);
      return promise;
  })
  .redirectPath('/')
everyauth.facebook
    .appId("secretId")
    .appSecret("secret")
    .findOrCreateUser( function (session, accessToken, accessTokenExtra, fbUserMetadata) {
      var promise = this.Promise();
      User.findOrCreateByUidAndNetwork(fbUserMetadata.id, 'facebook', fbUserMetadata, promise);
      return promise;
    })
    .redirectPath('/');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({secret:'blablabla'}));
  app.use(everyauth.middleware()); // Yes, i'm use it
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router); // And it
  app.use(express['static'](__dirname + '/public'));
});

everyauth.helpExpress(app); // And this above that routes

app.dynamicHelpers({
    currentUser: function (req, res){
        return req.user; //it's empty!
    }
})

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true })); 
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler()); 
});

// Routes

app.get('/', routes.index);
require("./controllers/user");

app.listen(80);
```

Вот код модели пользователя:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    "uid":{type:String},    
    "name":{type:String},   
    "network":{type:String},
    "profile":{}        
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

var User = mongoose.model('User');
```

И функция поиска пользователя с заполнением promise:

```
this.findOrCreateByUidAndNetwork = function(uid, network, profile, promise) {
    User.find({uid: uid, network: network}, function(err, users) {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(users.length > 0) {
            promise.fulfill(users[0]);// <-- what i want:)
        } else {
            var user = new User();
            user.network = network;
            user.uid = uid;
            user.profile = profile;
            user.name = profile.first_name || profile.name;
            user.save(function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                promise.fulfill(user);
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Спасибо за внимание